Decoding gmail embedded images in ClickUp tasks description not working
I'm trying to do this workflow with Pipedream:

A Gmail account receives an email.
The message from the email is decoded, using the "text/plain" part (if it doesn’t exist, I use the "text/html").
Create a ClickUp task or update an existing one with that message.
Download attachments (not the embedded images, if i include them and upload those too, the task ended up  with signatures images, logos, etc as upload files, when i need them to be in the description of the task ).
Upload those attachments.

The thing is that decoding messages with embedded images is not working properly because embedded images can't be decoded with base64.
Is there a way to create the task with the description being the exact same email, with embedded images and all those kinds of things? Like i said before, i've tried to download those images as attachments and upload them, but the task ended up with those images as uploaded files; I need them to be in the description as embedded images.
This is how I decode the email:
import { htmlToText } from "html-to-text";

const decodeBase64 = (data) => {
  const normalizedBase64 = data.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
  const padding = normalizedBase64.length % 4;
  if (padding > 0) {
    normalizedBase64 += '='.repeat(4 - padding);
  }
  return Buffer.from(normalizedBase64, 'base64').toString('utf-8');
};

export default defineComponent({
  async run({ steps, $ }) {
    const email = steps.trigger.event.payload;
    const text = {
      mimeType: "",
      data: "",
    }
    const parts = email.parts;

    if(email.mimeType.includes("multipart")){
      function findEmailText(parts){
        for(const part of parts){
          const subParts = part.parts;
          if(subParts){
            findEmailText(subParts);
          }
          if(part.mimeType === "text/plain" || part.mimeType === "text.html"){
            text.mimeType = part.mimeType;
            text.data = part.body.data;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      findEmailText(parts);
    } else {
      text.mimeType = email.mimeType;
      text.data = email.body.data; 
    }

    text.decodedMessage = text.mimeType !== "text/html" ? decodeBase64(text.data) : htmlToText(decodeBase64(text.data), { wordwrap: 130 });
    
    return text.decodedMessage;
  },
})

And how i upload the attachments:
import { axios } from "@pipedream/platform"
import fs from "fs";
import FormData from "form-data";

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    clickup: {
      type: "app",
      app: "clickup",
    }
  },
  async run({ steps, $ }) {

    const { TMP_DIR } = steps.define_constants.$return_value;
    const taskId = steps.if_task.$return_value;
    const files = steps.download_attachments.$return_value;
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      const file = files[i];
      const filePath = `${TMP_DIR}/${file.filename}`;
      const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
      
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append(`attachment`, fileStream); 

      try {
        await axios($, {
          method: 'POST',
          url: `https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/task/${taskId}/attachment`,
          headers: {
            Authorization: `${this.clickup.$auth.oauth_access_token}`,
            ...formData.getHeaders(),
          },
          data: formData,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error message:', error.message);
      }
    }
  
    return `Uploaded ${files.length} files successfully.`;
  }
})

